# Architecture for messaging library C++

Tags: c++, object-oriented-design, inheritance

I have a library, which sends and receives a set of binary messages and parses them.

So far I’ve used inheritance for my design, i.e.

```
class BaseMsg 
{
    // init msg from rx'd binary stream
    virtual bool fromBinary(std::vector<char> b) = 0;
    // write msg content to binary stream to tx
    virtual std::vector<char> toBinary() const = 0;

   MsgType type;
};

class MsgA : public BaseMsg 
{
    MsgA()
    {
        type = MsgType::A;
    }

    bool fromBinary(std::vector<char> b)
    {
        // parse binary stream here and init members
    }

    std::vector<char> toBinary() const
    {
        // encode members to binary stream here
    }
private:
    std::string freetext;
    // more members
};

class MsgB : public BaseMsg
{
    MsgB()
    {
        type = MsgType::B;
    }

    bool fromBinary(std::vector<char> b)
    {
        // parse binary stream here and init members
    }

    std::vector<char> toBinary() const
    {
        // encode members to binary stream here
    }
private:
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    // more members
};
```

In addition I have a messaging class `Messenger`, which has methods to send and receive, i.e.

```
bool sendMessage(std::unique_ptr<BaseMsg> msg)
{
    std::vector<char> bin = msg->toBinary();
    // send bin
}

std::unique_ptr<BaseMsg> receive(std::vector<char> receivedBinaryStream)
{
    if (/*check in binary stream, if msg is MsgA*/)
    {
        auto msg = std::make_unique<MsgA>();
       msg->fromBinary(receivedBinaryStream);
    return std::move(msg);
    }
if (/*check in binary stream, if msg is MsgB*/)
    {
        auto msg = std::make_unique<MsgB>();
       msg->fromBinary(receivedBinaryStream);
    return std::move(msg);
    }
}
```

This works quite well, but when using the library I end up casting a lot from the base class to a specific sub class.
This is especially after reception of a message and using the message in my application.

```
// 
auto msg = messenger.receive(binStream);

if (msg->type == MsgType::A)
{
    // cast to MsgA and continue processing
}
else if (msg->type == MsgType::B)
{
    // cast to MsgB and continue processing
}
```

So the question is, if there's an alternative architecture/design, which would avoid the casts in the last code sample.

The question is not for details of the implementation, but if there's a better design than currently using inheritance.

**edit:**

Messages have different parameters, e.g. MsgA provides free text, MsgB provides location info of an object, etc.

Therefore when a message is consumed by the application, it's casted to its sub class to obtain the type specific parameters.

Comment: I think you'd want to share more with us.  The main thing I'd be interested in is where you discover that the message is type A, so instantiate a `MsgA`, but presumably soon thereafter, treat it as `BaseMgs`, loosing the concrete type.

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to make it reasonably answerable here.  At a minimum, we would need to see *actual* class names and descriptions of their functionality, not `foobar` names, and perhaps a bit more code.

Comment: Also, doesn't C++ support [runtime polymorphism?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/virtual-functions-and-runtime-polymorphism-in-c-set-1-introduction/) You shouldn't need to cast much.  If you are, it means that your subclasses aren't overriding your virtual methods in `BaseMsg` properly.

Comment: extended my example to make it a little bit clearer hopefully.

Comment: I don't see the problem.  I don't see the casts.

Comment: sorry for not being clearer. improved the post again.

Comment: I still don't see the casts.  Checking the message type is reflection, but that isn't a cast.

Comment: For the moment I just wrote a comment where the cast happens, because right now I don't have access to the code

Comment: I've got two possible courses of action.  (1) Make pessimistic assumptions, and bash your architecture.  (2) Flag the questions as unclear.  (3) Wait 24 hours, then do 1 of 2.  (btw, before I jump to assumptions) What's the format of the message?  It can be important for the architecture of the handler.

Comment: Honestly I don't get your hostility. If the question is unclear, please explain what should be clarified. If you check the edit history I made multiple edits to improve the question, if that's still not sufficient I'm more than happy to add more clarification.

Comment: Sufficient details aren't provided after multiple requests by several users.  You are complaining about casts.  There are no casts in your code.  This line wouldn't even compile `auto msg = st::make_unique<BaseMsg>();`.  So perhaps this isn't even a real program.  -1 and flagging as unclear.

Comment: Sorry for not making the question clear enough yet, I'm trying to make it more clear. Question was not aimed at the details of the implementation, but rather asking if there's maybe a design which could be better. The provided code is a reduction from a  more complex real-world code with maybe too much reduction at the moment.

Comment: Is there a reason you're writing your own serialisation and delivery library instead of using well known tools like Google Protocol Buffers (serialisation) and ZeroMQ (message delivery) or even RabbitMQ?     If there are any reasons why those tools don't meet your requirements, consider at least looking at their design as a guideline because you'll probably find that many of the same principles apply, since you seem to be essentially solving the same problem.

Comment: @Ben Cottrell: main reason is that the library is older than Protobuf.

Comment: @Simon The key point to be able to write an answer is: Why do you need to cast at all? In other words: Why does the `BaseMsg` interface not provide all the functionality you need? Without at least semi-realistic example code that at the very least includes the lines that actually do the cast, a useful answer is impossible.

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: Double dispatch would let the compiler do the casts for you. Framing an answer on my phone isn't easy, but think of a MedsageProcessor class with a set of consume() methods - one per specific message type.

Comment: If you only have 1 type of handler per Msg, in my opinion it could be a virtual method in Base and concrete in the MsgX class. Otherwise use the strategy pattern, by requesting to handle a "certain" situation calling a virtual method from base, but handled differently depending on concrete class. Or pass in a factory of strategies, let the MsgX decide which strategy it needs, or... As you can see we need more info, to give good advice on your situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, **separate messages from their handlers**.

Instead of having `MessageTypeA` handle its own parsing to and from binary; introduce an intermediary `MessageHandlerTypeA` which does this. This way you can reduce the messages themselves to Plain Ol' Data types or - at the very least - simple data containers, and you can keep the actual handlers instanced throughout instead of creating them new each time.

Then in your message receiving code you can register for each message type which `MessageHandler` to pass the binary data to. This is extensible from outside the library since you can then expose the registration function to allow new messages to be arbitrarily interpreted.

Second, **use callbacks** to do further message handling.

Instead of the `receive` and then process approach you are using, have the `MessageHandler` decode the message into the appropriate `message` type and then call any code that needs to know about that particular message. Your calling code, then, rather than interpreting the message simply registers a callback with the handler and then receives a callback with the interpreted message whenever that message is received.